# How to get audio file duration in react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was just trying to get the duration of the the audio file. By default, audio property is not exist on file. I only only size, name and type property in the file. How I can get duration of audio file in seconds.

Thnaks

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple things you need to do. First, I assume you are using an `audio` tag to render the audio, right? If yes, you need to add two things.

- Add a `ref` property to the audio tag so you are able to check it's duration
- Add the `onLoadedMetadata` property to the audio tag. This will only trigger when the metadata for the audio you provided is available. With this callback, you can then access your audio reference property `duration`.

Example code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const Audio = () => {
    const audioRef = useRef();

    const onLoadedMetadata = () => {
        if (audioRef.current) {
            console.log(audioRef.current.duration);
        }
    };

    return (
        <audio
            ref={audioRef}
            onLoadedMetadata={onLoadedMetadata}
        >
            <source src="your_audio_url" type="audio/x-wav" />
        </audio>
    );
};
```

Comment: I am using  and uploading files locally, secondly   audioRef.current.duration is giving type error

Comment: Property 'duration' does not exist on type 'never', this is error

Comment: You didn't mention TS. You can do this I think: `const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);`

Comment: About the files being local or remote, I don't think it makes a difference or does it? If you are rendering the audio files, this is how you get that information. If you are not rendering them, then I don't know how you get that information, maybe with a external library? You also didn't specify that in your question

Answer (score -1):

```
        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file) //file[0
        const audio = document.createElement("audio")
        audio.src = objectUrl

        audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
          setMusicDuration(audio.duration)
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**